# Extreme values in histogram plotting bins

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-science, data-visualization, histogram

I am trying to plot values in histogram but there are cases where there are extreme values that I cannot deal with for example value like 1,2,25,35,23,60 are plotted correctly but values like 1,23, 45, 60, 1000, 45000 are so distant that the xScale is taking domain as (1, 4500) and then the values plotted are very distant. Is there any way we can group the last elements together ? Since I am using the same xScale domain so the bins are also generated in a similar fashion for this histogram as mentioned below

```
  histogram = d3
            .histogram()
            .value((d) => d.value)
            .domain(xScale.domain())
            .thresholds(xScale.ticks(threshold));

  bins = histogram(data)
```

Basically what I think here is I need to adjust the domain of the xScale (if I am right) to get the bins correct. I would like to get it something like >100 and combine the last two values of 1000 and 4500 and plot then on the same bar considering the above scenario.

Comment: Useful and related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160431/outliers-in-axes-in-d3-mixing-numerical-and-categorical-specifications

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg></svg>
    <script>
      // set up normal graph
      var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 50,
        },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // our bin size will be segments of 10
      // with a max of 100
      // anything over 100 will be binned together
      var binSize = 10,
          binLimit = 100;

      // some fake data, 100 points < 100
      // 10 points possibly > 100
      var data = d3
        .range(100)
        .map(() => {
          return { value: Math.random() * binLimit };
        })
        .concat(
          d3.range(10).map(() => {
            return { value: Math.random() * 5000 };
          })
        );

      // max value in data set
      var maxValue = d3.max(data, (d) => {
        return d.value;
      });

      // set the parameters for the histogram
      var histogram = d3
        .histogram()
        .value((d) => {
          return d.value;
        })
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        // thresholds would be [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        // so anything >100 will be binned at end
        .thresholds(d3.range(0,110,10));

      var bins = histogram(data);

      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width])
        // set our scale to have a domain with two extra increments at the end
        .domain([0, binLimit + (binSize * 2)]);

      // set up svg object
      var svg = d3
        .select('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      // add x-axis
      svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .attr('class', 'x-axis')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // y-axis
      var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
      y.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(bins, function (d) {
          return d.length;
        }),
      ]);

      svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      var bWidth = x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1

      // append our rects
      svg
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(bins)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 1)
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
          if (d.x1 > 100){
            // if this is the last bin
            // place it in our special column on the end
            return 'translate(' + x(binLimit + binSize) + ',' + y(d.length) + ')';
          } else {
            return 'translate(' + x(d.x0) + ',' + y(d.length) + ')';
          }
        })
        .attr('width', bWidth)
        .attr('height', function (d) {
          return height - y(d.length);
        })
        .style('fill', '#69b3a2');

      // modify last two labels
      document.querySelector('.x-axis .tick:nth-last-child(2)')
        .children[1].innerHTML = '>100';
      document.querySelector('.x-axis .tick:nth-last-child(1)')
        .children[1].innerHTML = '<5000';

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like this is the solution but what I am using is xScale.domain for histogram domain and xScale.ticks for threshold of histogram. This is because I am not aware of the data that would come in and the interval which in the above case you have already considered as 100 & 10 respectively. Like I may get values ranging from 1-10 or even values ranging from 1-1000. In that case how am I supposed to calculate the interval and extreme values since I am using xScale as mentioned above.

Comment: @KishanVikani, do you know what the "cut-off" should be for the extreme values are are you trying to figure that out dynamically as well?

Comment: Yes I don't know the cut-off as well, that is the reason I was trying to use xScale for things but idk how it would work. Also using ticks might work or not idk since the ticks function may sometimes return less than expected ticks so. Confused on how to implement the above approach with dynamic data and intervals.

Comment: Also, for example I have value as [9k, 10k, 12k,15k, 120k, 250k,80k, 100k] and also these values can range as [500, 600, 700, 750, 1k, 1.2k, 900]. These two are some data from my original data set and they also don't start from 0 necessarily and don't have fixed intervals between ticks when using a xScale. Also I don't want that all values  get plotted against a particular threshold, just collect the last few points that are very outside the majority plotting to be grouped.

Comment: Refer the answer that you gave [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393713/d3js-updating-histogram-elements-not-working-general-update-pattern). It's just that some values are very far in this example and I want to group them, other plotting remains same.